# How can I plot the correlation between app downloads and session duration?

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization, ggplot2, matplotlib

For example, the data could be:

App A, 100-500 downloads, 20 mins

App B, 100-500 downloads, 75 mins

App C, 500-1000 downloads, 30 mins

and so on. I want the overall correlation as well as app-wise distinction (if possible). What kind of plot should I use?

Comment: Do you know the exact number of downloads? Why you do bin that variable?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overall correlation" and what does "app-wise distinction" mean?

Comment: @NickCox the exact number is not known, only ranges are. So it is necessary to bin them.

Comment: @whuber, sorry I wasn't very clear. I mean I want to see "the general relation between number of downloads and session duration" but I don't want to club together Apps A and B for example, just because they are in the same download range.

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- data.frame(name = c("App A", "App B", "App C"),
                downloads = ordered(c("100-500", "100-500", "500-1000"),
                                levels=c("0-100","100-500", "500-1000", ">1000")),
                duration = c(20, 75, 30))

plot(as.integer(downloads) ~ duration, data=d, yaxt="n", ylim=c(0.5,4.5), pch=16,
     ylab="Downloads")
axis(side = 2, at=1:4, labels = c("0-100","100-500", "500-1000", ">1000"))
abline(h=1:4, col="grey", lty=2)
```

yields this:

[image]

Try adding the following to add the Apps's names in the plot:

```
text(d$duration, as.integer(d$downloads)+.2, labels = d$name)
```

Comment: Could you explain how this code and graphic address the question, which is about "correlation"? What are the reasons you chose this kind of plot?  Why are the bins equally spaced on the y-axis?  Why doesn't the x-axis begin at zero?  Why does it show binned classifications ("0-100", ">1000") that do not exist in the dataset?

Comment: Shure. The question was "What kind of plot should I use?" and I think, that a scatter plot will be best to display graphically, what is meant by correlation. Spearman's correlation would be better addressed with ranks of duration on the x-axis but I don't want to give away the metric scale in the plot. So I think that this is a good plot to add to a calculation of Spearman correlation where Pearson correlation does not make sense with an ordinal y-axis. The y-axis is equally spaced in lack of any other informative distance.

Comment: (continued:) The plot is an example as an answer to an example dataset so I took the freedom to add more bins in order to make my suggestion/example as clear as possible. Whether or not the original poster decides to include x = 0 in his plot or not is entirely up to him and will depend on his original data and personal preferences.

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard. I understand your choice of equal-sized bins. But what if I have a greater range, and unequal-sized bins? For example, Google Play shows install counts in ranges such as (5,000,000 - 10,000,000), (10,000,000 - 50,000,000), (50,000,000 - 100,000,000) and (100,000,000 - 500,000,000). What is the best way to represent in this case?

Comment: First: This is not a strictly a logatirhmic scale, but it's realted to a logarithmic scale. And it is not a random scale. It presents what some Google engineers would call "the next big step we should mention". So the unit on the y-axis could be "steps of which Google engineers believe, they make a difference". Thus: equal spacing! Second: Even if you have alternative scales, that do not lend themselves to an easy explanation like "quasi-logarithmic": Even for nominal data, which has noch distance at all, this kind of diagramm is used on a regular basis.